# what is the meaning of transformGlobalPlan in goalfunction.cpp line 80

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, local-planner, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/**

- @brief  Transforms the global plan of the robot from the planner frame to the frame of the costmap,
- selects only the (first) part of the plan that is within the costmap area.
- @param tf A reference to a transform listener
- @param global_plan The plan to be transformed
- @param robot_pose The pose of the robot in the global frame (same as costmap)
- @param costmap A reference to the costmap being used so the window size for transforming can be computed
- @param global_frame The frame to transform the plan to
- @param transformed_plan Populated with the transformed plan
  */

bool transformGlobalPlan(const tf::TransformListener& tf,

```
const std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& global_plan,
  const tf::Stamped<tf::Pose>& global_robot_pose,
  const costmap_2d::Costmap2D& costmap,
  const std::string& global_frame,
  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& transformed_plan);
```

what is the meaning of this function?
I have got the global_plan from the globalPlanner in the global_frame,have I?
Why and when should I call this function?
and what is "the planner frame",Does it equal to the global_frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270733/what-is-the-meaning-of-transformglobalplan-in-goalfunction.cpp-line-80/) by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

now , I have figure it out . I found that if you already had a plan in global_frame not in odom_frame and you can use that plan for base_local_planner directly . the lookuptranform() and tranform  is not necessary

---

Originally posted by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) with karma: 138 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-07-15**:
You would also need to prune the `global plan` according to the size of the `local costmap`.